# Nodejs save uploaded file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer

I have an application and in that application, I want to use some file upload mechanism.

My requirement is:

Once the file is uploaded, its name will be changed to something unique, like uuid4(). I will store this name in the database later.

I have written something like that, however I have a couple of questions:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
router.post('/', middleware.checkToken, upload.single('file'), (req,res,next)=>{

    // key:
    // file : "Insert File Here"

    console.log("req:");
    console.log(req.file);
    const str = req.file.originalname
    var filename = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf('.'));
    // I will use filename and uuid for storing it in the database
    // I will generate unique uuid for the document and store the document
    // with that name
    var extension = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, str.length);

    // HERE!

    res.status(200).json();

})
```

I have seen examples of storing it in the diskStorage:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

However, as far as I understood, this is a configuration outside of the API call. Meaning that I cannot modify it every time I call this API. I want to assign different names to the file, and I need that name(uuid) to save that name in the database.

How can I preserve such functionality?

Comment: `filename` is called every time a file is uploaded, so you get a different identificator. Then, the new name should be avialable at `req.file`

Comment: @Rashomon, so, if I denote the name as uuid, I can reach this name from the API call `req.file.fieldname`?

Comment: I have a working example in front of me and its stored in a property called `filename` yes. Its not exactly the same, since I use multiupload

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rashomon and @Eimran Hossain Eimon, I have solved the issue. In case of anyone wonders the solution, here it is:

```
const multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        // the file is saved to here
        cb(null, '/PATH/TO/FILE')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // the filename field is added or altered here once the file is uploaded
        cb(null, uuidv4() + '.xlsx')
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


router.post('/', middleware.checkToken, upload.single('file'), (req,res,next)=>{
    // the file is taken from multi-form and the key of the form must be "file"

    // visible name of the file, which is the original, uploaded name of the file
    const name = req.file.originalname;

    // name of the file to be stored, which contains unique uuidv4
    const fileName = req.file.filename;
    // get rid of the extension of the file ".xlsx"
    const file_id = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

    // TODO
    // Right now, only xlsx is supported
    const type = "xlsx";

    const myObject = new DatabaseObject({
        _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        file_id: file_id,
        name : name,
        type: "xlsx"
    })

    myObject .save()
    .then(savedObject=>{
        // return some meaningful response
    }).catch(err=>{
        // return error response
    })
})
```

This solves my current issue. Thanks for helping. For future improvements, I'll add error case for:

- In case uuidv4 returns an id which already exists(I believe it is highly unlikely since the object contains some timestamp data), rerun the renaming function.
- In case there is an error in saving to the database, I should delete the uploaded file to avoid future conflicts.

If you have solutions for those problems too, I'm much appreciated.

Comment: 1: If you already used a long timestamp its enough. 2: In case theres an error saving to DB, catch the error on `save()` function and delete the file with `filename` name

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it wrong... you said that

> I cannot modify it every time I call this API.

But actually, the `filename` is called every time for every file. Let me explain this portion of code...

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
```

Here look at the `callback` function (denoted by `cb`) :

- 1st argument `null` in callback function is like *convention*. You always pass `null` as the first argument in a callback function. [See this Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518978/nodejs-callback-with-null-as-first-argument)
- 2nd argument determines what the file should be named inside the `destination` folder. **So, here you can specify any function, which can return you a *unique* filename every time.**

Since you are using mongoose... 
I think it would be better if you implement your `function uniqueFileName()` using the `mongoose method` within your Schema (in which you want to save the file path) and call it in your route handler. [Learn More](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. No need. Because you're using timestamps.
2. In case of an error in saving to the database, you can delete the uploaded file using this code to avoid future conflicts. Try this:

   ```
   const multer = require('multer');
   const fs = require('fs'); // add this line
   var storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req, file, cb) {
           // the file is saved to here
           cb(null, '/PATH/TO/FILE')
       },
       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
           // the filename field is added or altered here once the file is uploaded
           cb(null, uuidv4() + '.xlsx')
       }
   })
   var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


   router.post('/', middleware.checkToken, upload.single('file'), (req,res,next)=>{
       // the file is taken from multi-form and the key of the form must be "file"

       // visible name of the file, which is the original, uploaded name of the file
       const name = req.file.originalname;

       // name of the file to be stored, which contains unique uuidv4
       const fileName = req.file.filename;
       // get rid of the extension of the file ".xlsx"
       const file_id = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

       // TODO
       // Right now, only xlsx is supported
       const type = "xlsx";

       const myObject = new DatabaseObject({
           _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
           file_id: file_id,
           name : name,
           type: "xlsx"
       })

       myObject .save()
       .then(savedObject=>{
           // return some meaningful response
       }).catch(err=>{
           // add this
           // Assuming that 'path/file.txt' is a regular file.
           fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('path/file.txt was deleted');
           });
       })
   })
   ```

also see [NodeJS File System Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)